# Is this plugin safe? Googletalkpluginaccel.msi

Tags: windows-7, plugins, google-talk

I keep getting a message from Komodo that this plugin wants access to my computer. However, the plugin is unsigned. I have looked and looked but am not sure that this is a valid Google plugin.

Can you advise me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked it with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)? A Google search only reveals third party download sites. I would not say it is safe.

Comment: Did you download the .msi from a website you trust?

Comment: I did not specifically download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Google Talk for Windows** was [shutdown/Discontinued in 23 Feb 2015](https://plus.google.com/+MayurKamat/posts/ETBvtp9VYav)

If you had **/** have it installed, uninstall it and switch to **Google Hangouts** or whatever you like.

If it just popped up on its own with no signature **: /** that is so not cool. **UNSAFE**

Comment: I have hangouts now.